# Which NWoD books deal with mortal and kinfolk NPCs in the criminal, law, or political arenas?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

I'm running a Werewolf game and, after the pack managed to root out a Bale Hound and make the only other Rahu in the local area stand down, it seems like they want to take the time to handle mortal antagonists in their backstories. What I'd like to know is what NWoD books could provide good resources for kinfolk, criminal (mob or hackers especially), law and/or political characters.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One great resource for the criminal and law aspects of your question is **[Tales From the 13th Precinct](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/12203/World-of-Darkness%3a-Tales-from-the-13th-Precinct?it=1)**, a sourcebook from the core World of Darkness line that approaches the setting from a law-enforcement perspective. It not only prepares you to make characters on both sides of the law that can encounter the supernatural world, but it adds a few new merits and system tweaks to make them able to be a challenge for the Pack.

Comment: How did this book escape my notice? Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @Bigeshu It had a really small print run; a lot of the nWoD books in the core line did.

Comment: Well that explains it. I wonder if my flgs has a copy in the for sale bin. IF not, to amazon or troll and toad I go. I read about the book and it looks exactly like what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Bigeshu Good luck. If you don't find it there, you can acquire it through DriveThruRPG; I've turned the reference above into a link to the store.

Comment: Thanks again! Just picked up my copy and it's an amazing book.

Comment: I have to also throw in http://www.amazon.com/Dogs-World-Darkness-Richard-Clayton/dp/1588467147 Dogs of War, for when politics fail, and they bring in the big guns.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness:
To go with **Tales From the 13th Precinct** (which should definatly be your first point),
other (less useful, but still worth a look) books are,
the back section of **Armoury**,mostly talks about gun law,
and also **Dogs of War** which is about the military, but relevant (iirc) for things like border guards, and martial law. (I plan to use if for a game set in developing nations where you are more likely to encounter the national guard than police)

Conversly AFAIK, **Midnight Roads** doesn't have much wrt Law and order.

I feel link there must be other books, perhaps **City of the Damned**

nWoD Core does provide some guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check out the **Hunter: The Vigil** line as this deals with the humans (from small barely organized local groups to huge world spanning conspiracies) handle the supernatural monsters in the world.  Very specifically the expansion book **Spirit Slayers** looks much more closely at hunter groups that deals with werewolves and similar monsters.